# Why shouldn't there be a bar called Hot Main Posts, just like Hot Meta Posts?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, hot-questions-list, community-bulletin

In the main site, there is a bar on the right named **Hot Meta Posts** containing the good questions on the meta site. But there is no such bar showing the trending best questions on the main site. There maybe the **Hot Questions Bar** but they show good questions from all the 149 communities, which sometimes don't even contain more than 1 or 2 questions from *MathsSE*. There are however, many questions on the main site which get a lot of attention and lots of upvotes and brilliant answers almost everyday.

To find these questions, one has to scroll through 3 to 6 pages of 50 questions each to find out which questions got attention and which questions got good answers. This is very laborious.

But only 10k+ rep users have access to the Moderators Tools Option from where they can note down what are the highly voted, commented and edited questions and answers. Of course, these trusted users require the information to help the mods properly run the site.

Still there should be a bar on the right which should be visible to all the users in general so that they can also contribute to the questions and get helped by the answers.

[image]

Comment: I have added the tags ([meta-tag:community-bulletin]) (which is the name of the box with hot meta posts) and ([meta-tag:hot-questions-list]). If you think that these tags for some reason do not fit your question, feel free to remove them.

Comment: Just to make sure, you are aware that there exists [hot questions tab](http://math.stackexchange.com/?tab=hot) right?

Comment: It does not feature in the screen shot provided..... @MartinSleziak

Comment: As you probably found out from my link in the preceding comment, this tab is displayed when you go [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/) but not when you go [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions). To learn more about how the question on this tab are selected, see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4766/how-are-hot-questions-selected).

Comment: @MartinSleziak There are users like me who do not know about this. what about them? How should they be informed?

Comment: Well, my guess would be that we learn how the things work on this site simply by using it. For example, I did not know about list of highly voted questions/answers in [moderator tools](http://math.stackexchange.com/tools?tab=stats). But I have learned about them from your post. (And I would have learned about them sooner if I had spent more time playing with 10k+ mod tools.)

Comment: Since you have mentioned that network-wide hot questions *sometimes don't even contain more than 1 or 2 questions from MathsSE*, it might be worth pointing out that many questions from this site cannot enter that list simply because [the titles contain MathJaX](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/20482/do-questions-with-latex-in-titles-appear-in-hot-questions).

Answer (score 4):

I think that the reason that "Hot Meta Posts" exists is that the Meta needs more attention than the main site (for obvious reasons). Since the main site gets much more visibility, there is no need for an extra box calling attention to it.